# Find all controls inside WPF Listbox

Tags: wpf

I want to access all buttons inside the WPF Listbox, here is my xaml code.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MouseDown="myStackPanel_MouseDown"  MouseUp="myScrollViewer_MouseMove"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="435" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Width="250" Margin="0,-4,-4,-4" ScrollChanged="scrollerVideoCategory_ScrollChanged">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="StackPanleEmployee" Margin="40,0,0,0" MouseDown="myStackPanel_MouseDown"  MouseUp="myScrollViewer_MouseMove"   Loaded="StackPanleVideoCategory_Loaded" >
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxEmployeVideoType" MouseDown="myStackPanel_MouseDown"  MouseUp="myScrollViewer_MouseMove"  BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#E2E2E2">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200" Name="myStackPanel" MouseDown="myStackPanel_MouseDown"  MouseUp="myScrollViewer_MouseMove" >
                            <Button  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ButtonVideoTabItemDefault}"   MouseUp="b_MouseMove"  Tag="{Binding Path}" Content="{Binding Name}" Name="btnSubCategory"  Click="btnVideoCategorySelection_Click"></Button>
                            <Separator Background="#E2E2E2" Margin="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

anyone have idea?

Comment: You forgot to post the code

Answer (score 3):

Somthing like this may do the trick

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the visual child.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="childItem">The type of the child item.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="obj">The obj.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }
                else
                {
                    var childOfChild = FindVisualChildren<T>(child);
                    if (childOfChild != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var subchild in childOfChild)
                        {
                            yield return subchild;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Just declare the type you want and the control that contains them

```
  var buttons = FindVisualChildren<Button>(ListBoxEmployeVideoType).ToList();
```

This is just a quick example and can be expanded to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetChildren() method of VisualTreeHelper or LogicalTreeHelper class. [Ref SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx)

Visual tree represents all elements that renders in UI whereas logical tree essential structure of UI. You can read about details about the usage [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in)

Hope this helps.